# A different type of ID Request?

Tags: support, identification-questions

While browsing the internet I saw an advertisement  for anime merchandise. I saw a character (monster rather) in the ad that looked quite cool. So I drew it out real quick. (I don't have the original pic from the net anymore so I can't reverse search it). But I don't really know which anime that character is from, and would like to find out. So if I post a picture of my drawing on the main site, will I be answered, or will my question be closed as an ID request? I know actual picture identification requests aren't allowed, but mine is just a quick sketch (if that makes any difference). It's fine with me if it isn't allowed, but I just wanted to check once, because I have seen people asking questions related to actual merchandise.. And sometimes they have been answered...

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be a superbad version of the ID request we already don't like. Not only you don't have the original screenshot/scan of the image, but it might be distorted by your imperfect recollection. That's not useful for anyone other than yourself, and that's exactly the type of question the SE network doesn't want to attract.

But for such a case, I'd recommend delving deep into your browser's history and maybe looking through cached images that may have been saved somewhere on your computer. Maybe you'll be able to find some clues about where you saw it.

If it's from an ad block on a specific site, you may have luck finding it by updating the page, getting new ads.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks. Guess I'll have to keep searching. Btw, the word Jaeger was written below it, and it looked like a giant humanoid, with some steam coming out of its mouth. And green eyes. Would you know something related to that ?

Comment: You can always hop into our chat where more than just the people who browse these meta questions might catch your message. We do occasionally help people find stuff in chat if they are cooperative.

Comment: Isn't there some minimum reputation required to access chat ? Or can anybody use it ?

Comment: I think you have enough rep. Get in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-

Comment: @Nightshade If you haven't found the source yet, see if [Pacific Rim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Rim_(film)) matches what you remember. It's an American film made in the style of mecha anime; it has giant robots called Jaegers who fight kaiju (monsters similar to Godzilla).

Comment: No actually I found it...it was Attack On Titan. By the way I have seen Pacific Rim too. Thanks a lot anyways : )